# two chapters on same page in memoir

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, memoir, chapters

I am writing a preface, which consists of roughly ten sentences describing my work. I have to write this in both English and Swedish. Same content, merely different languages.

I have chosen to have both prefaces (or abstracts is probably the correct term) on a single page. I am having trouble making this work. Here is a MWE of my approach

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test 1}
This is a test

\chapter*{Test 2}
This is a test

\end{document}
```

This creates two different chapters. Is there a way to keep both chapters on the same page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use

```
{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Test 2}}
```

for the second "chapter". Note that it's grouped, to localize the scope of the `\clearpage` redefintion.

[image]