# No separated page for a table of content in a book class document

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, scrbook

I am using a book class (exactly scrbook) for my paper. Still I don't want to have a separated page for my table of content -- the paper is a MSc thesis and I want the toc to start at the same page as the abstract. How can it be done?

Comment: You can try the same trick as in [two chapters on same page in `memoir`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88785/5764): `{\let\clearpage\relax\tableofcontents}`

Comment: Thanks. More or less works. -- It needed `\vadjust` in my case.