# Two chapters on same page in memoir, with twocolumn

Tags: spacing, memoir, chapters

This is a follow-up to the question [two chapters on same page in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88785)

```
\documentclass[oneside,landscape,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test 1}
This is a test

\lipsum[1-5]

{\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Test 2}}
This is a test

\end{document}
```

I'm trying to make a chapter start on the same page as existing content (to save place when printing partial drafts, as the bibliography starts a new chapter, and a new page for a couple of references). However the `\let\clearpage\relax` solution does not work, as it places the chapter title above the content of the previous chapter.

The `Test 2` chapter title appears above the end of the `\lipsum`, which is in the first chapter:

[image: Chapter title above lipsum]

Also, if I change the `\lipsum[1-5]` to `\lipsum[1-4]`, I get an intriguing error:

```
.tex:11: LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 {\let\clearpage\relax\chapter*{Test 2}
                                           }
```

How can I make `\chapter` and `\bibliography` start on the same page?

Comment: If you 'kill' `\clearpage`, LaTeX will get problems with floats

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The problem is that there aren't any floats here. I suspect the chapter title is inserted as a kind of float, probably due to an internal hack to position it the right way.
The `\let\clearpage\relax` solution (from the linked answer) does work with a single-column document, but doesn't with a `twocolumn` one.

Comment: Well, `\@currentlist` seems to be filled -- perhaps you should use a different class!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks. The goal was to keep the memoir's features and typographical details, but save some paper when printing drafts. I ended up reproducing the A4 `\textwidth` and `\textheight` on an A5 page using the `geometry` package, and put the pages side-by-side with `pdfnup`.
I'm still curious about the details of why the error occurs only with twocolumn, and why `memoir` uses floats to display chapter titles :) .

Answer (score 3):

It's not so obvious in the MWE but in this class chapter headings span two columns, if I extend the title you see

[image]

this is implemented essentially by

```
\twocolumn[ the Title]
```

where `\twocolumn` does `\clearpage` (so flushing all floats) and then internally uses the same mechanism as `figure*` to put the spanning text over both columns. It checks that there are no pending floats before using the float mechanism, but because you have disabled `\clearpage` you get the error that correctly informs you that floats (or in this case, the title of the first chapter) have been lost.