# \nopagebreak doesn't work between two chapters

Tags: page-breaking

All chapters begin a new page by default. I want to remove this break between two short chapters. By the nopagebreak doesn't work. What can be the cause? Is there another way to do that?
I don't give all my code there, but I can write some details if needed.

Comment: Can you please provide an MWE that shows the behaviour?

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a different level than `\chapter`.

Comment: a \nopagebreak stops tex choosing a page break but it does not stop \clearpage issued by chapter from forcing  break

Comment: One possibility is to temporarily `\let\clearpage\par` and restore it after starting the new chapter. I am not sure if there will be side effects though.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [two chapters on same page in `memoir`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88785/5764)

Answer (score 1):

As said, chapter insert a `\clearpage`, so a simple approach is place the chapter title in a group where this command if redefined to just make a paragraph break, some ornament or whatever that you want. After the group, the old definition of `\clearpage` is still in effect, so next chapters will start in new pages.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Uno}\lipsum[1]
\chapter{Dos}\lipsum[2]
\begingroup
\def\clearpage{\par}
\chapter{Tres}\lipsum[3]
\endgroup
\chapter{Cuatro}\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]